# SKAction playSoundFileNamed ERROR

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am getting this error after about 80 shots of a laser using a controlled Timer Interval so it fires every 0.2 seconds.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Failed to Load Resource', reason: 'Resource squish.mp3 can not be loaded'
*** First throw call stack:

Here is the code I use to play the sound and create the laser. squish.mp3 is an audio file that is played when an object is destroyed. Can anyone help? Is SKAction not very good for playing sound?

```
SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"lazer.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
[self runAction:sound];
[self removeActionForKey:@"sound"];
SKSpriteNode *laser = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fire"];
```

Comment: I am suffering the same problem. Did you recover from this problem?

Comment: Hi yes I replaced the sound file with a different one and it seemed to fix it. It now fires every 3rd of a second (laser sound) and I have not managed to crash it even after 1000 shots. Haven' tested past that. @Banshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't try this but I just replaced the sound file and it seems to have cured it. However, if there was an error with the audio file why did it play around 200 times before crashing.

Comment: You will still run into problems if you continually call 

    runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("file.wav"))

You should look at the solution  [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjFpb31u8LHAhUDL4gKHcSpD6U&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F26683171%2Fskaction-playsoundfilenamed-crashes-when-repeat-sprite-kit&ei=a3LbVYXEOIPeoATE076oCg&usg=AFQjCNFl_6AEPf4VOQmTltDz8yAhISWZDw&sig2=FMVNc_iBJhje8dNiD1Yl4A)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue ..! sound file run continues more then 100 time and after that crash with missing error!

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem and I think I have a solution, though I'm not sure. I haven't seen the same crash in a while though.

Make a single `SKAction` that represents playing the laser sound, and reuse that object.

I think `playSoundFileNamed:` is supposed to be smart about not re-loading the audio file from the file system every time it's used. But the crash indicates that it does get reloaded, at least occasionally. Keeping an SKAction around to reuse means that the audio file is only loaded once.

Comment: Nope tried it didn't work. Thank you though for your suggestion. I read another review that said just use CGAudio so maybe I will do that.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. It seemed to help me. It does seem to me that audio was more of an afterthought in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a more Apple-compatible format, like AAC (`.m4a`) for the sound file. Apple doesn't take too kindly with `.mp3`s. However, I think the file can be a Microsoft `.wav` file